# How to monitor the change of a variable from another dll?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, variables, event-handling

Here is what I have not figured out:
I want my main program to monitor a variable from another dll(thread); This variable is a `bool` flag that varies between true and false depending on the external hardware trigger. Here is what I did, but apparently it was not responding to the change of the variable:

```
public bool IsTriggerOn
{
    get { return TriggerWatcherDll.IsTriggerOn; }
    set
        {
             _isTriggerOn= TriggerWatcherDll.IsTriggerOn = value;
             if (_isTriggerOn == true)
             {
                  System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Trigger is ON!");
             }
         }
}
```

How exactly should I do this? Thanks.

I am using C# + WPF, and the code above is from a C# code behind a xaml;

Comment: Define an event for this. There must be a way to notice the change for you program. You can then fire an event. What are you working on precisely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you might be confusing yourself slightly. The fact that the TriggerWatcherDll class is in a different assembly does not appear to be relevant, based on the code sample you've given.
In fact, it looks like you are accessing IsTriggerOn as a static property of the class (based on the naming used), so the different thread is also not relevant to detecting the change (although, race conditions are a possibility).

From what you've described, it sounds like you just need an event in your "other" DLL:

```
class TriggerWatcherDll
{
    public static event EventHandler TriggerChanged;

    private static bool _trigger = false;
    public static bool IsTriggerOn
    {
        get { return _trigger; }
        set
        {
            if (_trigger != value)
            {
                _trigger = value;
                if (TriggerChanged != null)
                    TriggerChanged.Invoke(null, new EventArgs());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then just subscribe to the event in your main DLL:

```
class OtherDll
{
    public OtherDll()
    {
        TriggerWatcherDll.TriggerChanged += TriggerWatcherDll_TriggerChanged;
    }

    void TriggerWatcherDll_TriggerChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (TriggerWatcherDll.IsTriggerOn)
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Trigger is ON!");
    }
}
```

You might want to reconsider your use of static, though, and I haven't touched on threading problems.

Comment: Yeah I got the idea. I simply added event handlers in the DLL being called, then I added event responder/function in main thread, and ti worked!. Thanks alot. Answer accepted :)

Comment: 1) you should avoid static variables as much as you can 2) why do you use Invoke? 3) you should pass the trigger value in the event args to avoid 'threading problems'